# Class Assignment Problems

Tags: python

Why is PyDev giving me this error: "Class variable undefined" when I try to implement a simple class for an inversion counting algorithm? Here's my code:

```
from collections import deque

Class inversionCount:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def inversionMergeSort(m, n):
        print m
        if len(m) <= 1:
            n = 0
            return (m, n)
        half = len(m)/2
        left = m[0:half]
        right = m[half:]
        left = mergeSort(left)
        right = mergeSort(right)
        return inversionSort(left, right)

    def inversionSort(left, right, n):
        leftQueue = deque(i for i in left)
        rightQueue = deque(j for j in right)
        orderedList = []
        while len(leftQueue) > 0 or len(rightQueue) > 0:
            if len(leftQueue) > 0 and len(rightQueue) > 0:
                if leftQueue[0] < rightQueue[0]:
                    orderedList.append(leftQueue[0])
                    leftQueue.popleft()
                else:
                    orderedList.append(rightQueue[0])
                    if len(leftQueue) > 1:
                        self.n += len(leftQueue)
                    rightQueue.popleft()
            elif len(leftQueue) > 0:
                orderedList.append(leftQueue[0])
                leftQueue.popleft()
            elif len(rightQueue) > 0:
                orderedList.append(rightQueue[0])
                rightQueue.popleft()
        return (orderedList, n)
```

yet PyDev is failing to recognize that inversionCount is indeed a class. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, you are calling `inversionsSort()` at the end if `inversionMergeSort()` in the method namespace, where it is actually an instance method.  You need to call it on `self`. I'm also not quite sure why you have `self.n` in your `__init__()` even though you never access it, and pass `n` to both of the methods as required parameters.

Comment: @sr2222: Let's assume the OP never got to those points since he was stuck with the strange `Class variable undefined` error. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough, just looks like there's a bit of a design problem going on here, possibly related to a "Python is not Java" related misconception.

Comment: Yeah, I was initially trying to do the inversion count without a class, but I realized that passing in the n variable created a lot of unnecessary grunt work, so I decided to implement a class with an n variable that can be counted without being passed through the functions. When I posted this, I hadn't changed all of the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`class` is lowercase:

```
class inversionCount:
```

The error is thrown because the variable `Class` is indeed not defined; python is case sensitive and `Class` is not the same thing as `class`; the former is seen as a variable name, while `class` is a keyword.

If you were to run your code with the interpreter, it'll throw a syntax error instead; PyDev's interpretation is slightly different.